# FTP file to Mainframe

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

I am trying to FTP a JCL txt file to mainframe:

```
// Connect to the server
        ftp.connect(host);
        replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
        System.out.println(replyText);

        // Log into the server
        ftp.login(userId, password);
        replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
        System.out.println(replyText);


        // Tell the server to use the JES interface
        ftp.sendSiteCommand("FILETYPE=JES");
        replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
        System.out.println(replyText);

        //read JCL file in input stream
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        String originalFileName = "ca7jcl.txt";

        ftp.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);

        //store the JCL file
        ftp.storeFile(host, fileStream);
        replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
        System.out.println(replyText);
```

but getting 250-It is known to JES as *UNKNOWN
how can i resolve this?

Comment: Can you show the full output you are getting, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to run your JCL text file when FTP'ed.

Enclose `try {}` and `catch {}` block (if not done).

Here's the code (This works for me):

```
// FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient(); Assumed in your code
//Connect to the server 
try
{
    ftp.connect(host);
    replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
    System.out.println(replyText);
} catch (Exception  e)  { e.printStackTrace () ; }

//Login to the server 
try 
{ 
    ftp.login(userId, password);
    replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
    System.out.println(replyText);
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 

// Tell the server to use the JES interface
try
{ 
    // Instead of sendSiteCommand()
    // ftp.sendSiteCommand("FILETYPE=JES");

    // Try site() with everythng in lowercase
    ftp.site ("filetype=jes") ; 
    String replyText = ftp.getReplyString() ; 
    System.out.println (replyText) ; 
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 

//Submit the job from the text file.Use \\ to avoid using escape notation 
try 
{ 
    //read JCL file in input stream
    //String originalFileName = "ca7jcl.txt";

    String path = "" //Store your file's absolute path here 
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(path);

    //store the JCL file
    ftp.storeFile(host, fileStream);
    replyText = ftp.getReplyString();
    System.out.println(replyText);
 }  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Let us know if this helped. :)

Comment: Curious to know would you expect it to help. Looks like the Mainframe is bouncing it, probably an access issue or typo.

Comment: It works fine @BillWoodger What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried above way, for me I am getting issue with access like terminated with Return Code 8, Reason Code=0x11806f (Permission Denied.)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32436415)